# PowerMock - Mock private method doesn´t work

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to mock a private method with PowerMock but the method I mock to always returns 0. I show you my classes to see if you can help me. Thank you.

Service.class

```
public int getNumber() { return getNumberPriv(); }

private int getNumberPriv() {
    return 2;
}
```

ServiceTest.class

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class SharepointServiceTest {

@Test
 public void fakeTest() throws Exception {
         
     SharepointServiceImpl mock = PowerMockito.spy(new SharepointServiceImpl());

     PowerMockito.doReturn(7).when(mock, "getNumberPriv");
             
     int result = mock.getNumber(); //Always return 0
     
     assertNotNull(result);
     assertEquals(7, result);
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like you cannot mock calls to methods "within" the current class. There's no way to intercept the real call and hence no way to mock the response.